# Function to flatten multilevel array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of stdObjects, which are multilevel. I need to flatten them out.

Here is the array of objects:

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
        link => ''
        icon => ''
        title => 'Main'
        id => (int) 2
        children => [
            (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
                link => 'YTo0OntzOjEwOiJjb250cm9sbGVyIjtzOjU6InBhZ2VzIjtzOjY6ImFjdGlvbiI7czo3OiJkaXNwbGF5IjtzOjU6InBhc3MwIjtzOjQ6ImhvbWUiO3M6NToicGFzczEiO3M6MDoiIjt9'
                icon => 'fa-tachometer-alt'
                title => 'Dashboard'
                id => (int) 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I created following function to reduce the multilevel (can go to 4 levels deep) to single-level and converting the objects to a classic array:

```
function reduceArrayOfObjects(array $array, array $flatArray, $children = 'children') {
    foreach($array as $lvl1) {
        $lvl1 = (array) $lvl1;
        if(isset($lvl1[$children])) {
            reduceArrayOfObjects($lvl1[$children], $flatArray, $children);
            unset($lvl1[$children]);
        }
        $flatArray[] = $lvl1;
    }

    return $flatArray;
}

$multiLevel = []; // this is the array of objects
$newArray = [];
reduceArrayOfObjects($multiLevel, $newArray);
```

It won't work properly, I only get the first level back into my new array. I tried lots of variations on how to get to my result, but all of those are failing. When I hardcode all `foreach()` loops, it works...

This is my current output:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'link' => '',
        'icon' => '',
        'title' => 'Main',
        'id' => (int) 2
    ]
]
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: When you call the function recursively (`reduceArrayOfObjects($lvl1[$children]...`) you don't do anything with the return values.

Comment: I write them back to the `$flatArray` which I just give through recursively. Or is my logic nonsense?

Comment: The problem is that you either need to pass the value back and then do something with it, or pass the array by reference.  Not sure if `function reduceArrayOfObjects(array $array, array &$flatArray...` (with the extra `&`) will work, this is passing by reference.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you. It works with the `&`. *insert thank you gif*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NigelRen I found the solution.

I just had to add `&` to the function:

```
reduceArrayOfObjects(array $array, array &$flatArray, $children = 'children) {}
```